# android search contact after phone number

Tags: android, contacts

I have the following code:

```
public String getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number) {

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
        String name = "?";

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
                contactLookup.moveToNext();
                name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                //String contactId = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
            }
        } finally {
            if (contactLookup != null) {
                contactLookup.close();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return name;
    }
```

Here I am searching a contact name based on the full contact phone nummber. Is it possible to search contacs based just on 4 numbers from the phone number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the entire contacts numbers and names, use regex to get entries that match?